# Cache Control fails

Tags: php, html

My index.php page keeps being cached, showing old timer values and others, even though I'm using this:

```
session_cache_limiter( 'nocache' );
session_start( );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
```

to keep the browser from caching the page. I've checked the headers output in Firefly and they keep saying:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
```

I used to have this in the HTML META:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

But have already disabled those in order to check if they were interfering, but enabled or disabled doesn't make a difference.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: are you sure your header(...) line is being executed, and it doesn't send any warnings or errors? Have you checked your error logs? Otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Error_log = empty, no errors on the screen Headers output in FireFly is still Cache-Control private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 and added header( 'Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT' ); to the headers. And, timer still doesn't update.

Comment: Are you sure that it really is the browser that holds the document in its cache? Make sure there isn't any proxy between you and the server, that doe the caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Headers output in FireFly is still Cache-Control private,
>   max-age=10800, pre-check=10800, no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0

This implies that since you are setting this:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

Some other component/configuration in your app/page is setting this:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
```

and both are sent to the end user. The "Cache-Control: private" overrides your values when browser reads them, causing the page to be cached.

Note: [header() will by default override any headers that are previously set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), so it might be that something is setting that *after* your line of code, since your line should override any previous ones.

You need to find out what is setting those "private" cache-control headers and disable/comment that, otherwise it will not work. Maybe some other section later in your code?

Comment: Thanks for this, it was indeed an included file from the previous developer of the project that was setting the cache control to the other values.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cache expiration date to an old date.

```
header( 'Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT' );
```

Comment: Added your line to the code, but still get Cache-Control private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 and the timer still doesn't update. Not on   header( "refresh: 5; url=$redirectto" ), not clicking to another page, and going "back", not by clicking on a link back to the page from another page, not by refreshing the page.